# Disable full screen on youtube API - javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, fullscreen

How to disable youtube API being fullscreen? I use my custom video controller. However, double clicking video will make it enter fullscreen. I have tried to set player parameter 'fs':0 or set iframe attribute "allowfullscreen" to 0, but neither worked. Also, I don't want to set the youtube iframe css "pointer-event" into none. Because, sometimes youtube banner ads are annoying.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 player = new YT.Player('yt-player', {
  height: '360',
    width: '640',
  videoId: 'EoyU6FvgbJ4',
  playerVars: { 
   'controls': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
   'rel':0,
   'fs':0
    }
 });
}
```

```html
<div id="yt-player"></div>
```

Comment: *"However, double clicking video will make it enter fullscreen"* I tested your setup verbatim and clicking on video pauses said player.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax inside the "playerVars" is wrong, the following code worked for me :)

```
return new YT.Player(domElementId, {
  videoId: youTubeVidId,
  startSeconds:0,
  width: 820,
  height: 461,
  playerVars: {
    rel: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    fs: 0
  }
});
```

}

Comment: What exactely should be "wrong" in the OP's example code? It doesn't matter whether you declare properties as strings, i.e. `{'rel': 0}` is equivalent to `{rel: 0}`. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

JS, without testing it, but something like this should do the trick;

It will fire with **All** fullscreenchange events that run on the element.
it then proceeds to check for browser/prefix and execute a "exitFullscreen".

```
//videoElement is the ID of the html videoElement; e.g; <video id="thisIsIt">
videoElement.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function(){
  if (document.exitFullscreen) document.exitFullscreen();
  else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
  else if (document.msCancelFullScreen) document.msCancelFullScreen();
});
```